# How to extract the value "Data" in <td title> by using relative xpath in chrome for selenium testing

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Can you please help to find me the relative xpath of the td part

```html
<div class="abc" style="height: 24px; width: 172px; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px; cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(43, 136, 164);">
  <table class="Text" style="line-height: 1.3; width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td title="" style="overflow-wrap: break-word; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12pt; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; padding: 3px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Data for table</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For HTML code you have shared,you can use below:

```
//td[text()='Data for table']
```

But I would suggest please go through below link for better understanding:

https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/complete-guide-for-using-xpath-in-selenium-with-examples/